# Plugins not working in custom theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am doing theme integration in wordpress. I used many plugins but not working in my site. How can i fix this issue. displaying error like this

Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks

Comment: Where are you calling `wp_enqueue_script` in your theme? I'm guessing that your functions file has that incorrectly.  Please copy your `functions.php` code into your question.

Comment: @cale_b :i am new in wordpress so i  copy functions.php from by defalut theme. and using that file. but now noone plugin is working